# How to properly position text over full-page image (background) using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pic

I would like to be able to position text using coordinates using number of millimeteres from **top left corner**.

Using Tikz, I have the following tex code, which does appear to position the text above the image, but I can't work out how to control the positions. I have a hunch it is related to anchoring/ centering, but am not sure.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={200mm,200mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at (0mm,0mm) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm]{graph-paper.png}
  };
  \draw node[text width=80mm] at (0mm,20mm) {
    page 5 line 1
  };
  \draw node[text width=80mm] at (20mm,0mm) {
    page 5 line 2
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at (0mm,0mm) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm]{graph-paper.png}
  };
  \draw node[text width=80mm, anchor=north west] at (130mm,120mm) {
    page 6 line 1
  };
  \draw node[text width=80mm] at (30mm,50mm) {
    page 6 line 2
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that "page 6 line 1" completely does not appear on the page.

Question:

Can someone please show how to put some text within each quadrant of the page?

If the numbers/ coordinates used are such that `(0mm,0mm)` represents the top left corner, and `(200mm,200mm)` represents the bottom right corner, that would be ideal.

---

Image: [graph-paper.png](https://gist.github.com/bguiz/3bfb27bee138949a78eb7f38da6d0dc5/raw/b7b3a5d5d0a976487524a25f7ff49ad0d7392778/graph-paper.png)

Sample output: [book.pdf](https://gist.github.com/bguiz/3bfb27bee138949a78eb7f38da6d0dc5/raw/b7b3a5d5d0a976487524a25f7ff49ad0d7392778/book.pdf)

---

EDIT

Solution: Based on @jsbibra 's answer, with modifications to use `[anchor=northwest]` for each text node, and some changes to the `xshift` and `yshift` values.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={200mm,200mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0] at (current page.center) {
    \includegraphics[width=200mm]{graph-paper.png}
  };
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=20mm, yshift=-20mm] current page.north west) {
    page 4 line 1 NE quadrant
  };
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=120mm, yshift=-20mm] current page.north west) {
    page 4 line 2 NW quadrant
  };
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=20mm, yshift=-120mm] current page.north west) {
    page 4 line 3 SE quadrant
  };
  \draw node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=120mm, yshift=-120mm] current page.north west) {
    page 4 line 4 SW quadrant
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces an a PDF that looks like this:

[image: 4 quadrants]

... which is exactly what I was after.

Comment: one method is using `xshift=` or `yshift=`  or both options `xshift=3cm, yshift=5.5pt` as shown in the answer below

Comment: -- also added an option for placement with compass quadrants in the answer below as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={200mm,200mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node[inner sep=0, ]  {\includegraphics[width=200mm]{example-image}};
  \draw node[xshift=4cm]{page 5 line 1 };
  \draw node[] {page 5 line 2 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The other method--

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={200mm,200mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[]{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0]at(current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=200mm]{example-image}};
  \draw node[] at (current page.center) {page 6 line 1};
  \draw node[] at ([xshift=-3cm, yshift=-5cm]current page.north east) {page 6 line 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit2**

there are numerous permutations

the same code edited again

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw node[inner sep=0]at(current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}};
  \draw node[] at ($(current page.center)!0.5!([xshift=-3cm, yshift=-5cm]current page.north east)$) {page 6 line 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will give

[image]

Comment: Hmm, so if I ware to use current page.north west in combination with x shift and y shift, this might do what I am after.

Comment: you could also use compass points with intersections such as   `\draw node[] at ($(current page.center)!0.5!([xshift=-3cm, yshift=-5cm]current page.north east)$) {page 6 line 2};` 
 the part of the code  `($(current page.center)!0.5!([xshift=-3cm, yshift=-5cm]current page.north east)$)`  can be interpreted as midway between the two compass points center and north east offset by x and y shift  -- please have a look at the edit2 above  the 0.5 can be again replaced with 0.75 or 0.25 etc

Comment: Hmm thanks, I have tried it out, and managed to get it **almost** working - see edit to my question above.

So the position is slightly off compared to what I expect.
Is this because the coordinates of the text node are that if its "center" point?
If so, how can I I specify the coordinates of the "top right" corner of the text, instead of its center?

Comment: OK pls scratch the ^ above comment - just figured it out, and edited my answer to include the working solution.